# making a pseudo-static page

Tags: pages

I´m making a pseudo-static page that drives me loco.

The structures is:

- index.php --> with a footer that displays last 5 post title
- services.html --> this is pure static
- portfolio.html --> this is pure static
- blog.php --> this is the WP zone (http:/www.domain.com/blog)
- contact.html --> this is pure static

I better explain what I have:

**In index.php**

```
<?php 
/* Short and sweet */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('blog/wp-blog-header.php');
?>
<--- HTML --->
<h3>Recent Post</h3>                            
<?php get_archives('postbypost', '5', 'custom', '<li>', '</li>'); ?>
<--- HTML --->
```

**In page-blog.php**

```
<?php 
/* Short and sweet */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('blog/wp-blog-header.php');
?>
<--- HTML --->
<div class="span9">
<!-- Start the Loop. -->
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<!-- Test if the current post is in category 3. -->
<!-- If it is, the div box is given the CSS class "post-cat-three". -->
<!-- Otherwise, the div box is given the CSS class "post". -->
<?php if ( in_category('3') ) { ?>
<div class="post-cat-three">
<?php } else { ?>
<div class="post">
<?php } ?>

<!-- Display the Title as a link to the Post's permalink. -->
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

<!-- Display the date (November 16th, 2009 format) and a link to other posts by this posts author. -->
<small><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> by <?php the_author_posts_link() ?></small>

<!-- Display the Post's content in a div box. -->
<div class="entry">
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div>

<!-- Display a comma separated list of the Post's Categories. -->
<p class="postmetadata">Posted in <?php the_category(', '); ?></p>
</div> <!-- closes the first div box -->

<!-- Stop The Loop (but note the "else:" - see next line). -->
<?php endwhile; else: ?>

<!-- The very first "if" tested to see if there were any Posts to -->
<!-- display.  This "else" part tells what do if there weren't any. -->
<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>

<!-- REALLY stop The Loop. -->
<?php endif; ?>
</div> <!--cierra span 9-->

<div id="sidebar" class="span3">
<?php get_sidebar('right'); ?>
</div>

</div> <!-- /span 9-->
<--- HTML --->
```

The thing is that I´ve make the blog work, you can see the 5 post title in footer of the index.php, and can see the 5 post in the main blog.php file (with the global site style). But I can´t see each post individually. I would like to display the posts "in the same way" I have the blog.

I´ve been following several tuts and tricks but I´m not a programmer. I´ve read something about make a page into WP and link but didn´t work. I think the problem could be in the permalinks structure, but at this point I´m totally confused.

Comment: This is going to be hard to figure out without more information about how this all works. Things should mostly work automagically so you must have done something unusual.

Comment: Hi again. I´ve just bought a theme to make things easy. I´ve spend three days in trying to make this previous thing working with no luck, so I think it´s better to buy one and spend time adding content. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Create single.php in your themefolder and insert this code

get_header(); ?>

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

        <?php /* The loop */ ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
            <?php twentythirteen_post_nav(); ?>
            <?php comments_template(); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

Comment: That´s the single.php itself from the Twenty Thirteen theme...
Didn´t work.